# Expression: Bag of hammers

Tags: meaning

I know that there's a [film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1509787) with this title, but is it also a common English expression with stable meaning?

Comment: According to the extras on the DVD, the writer/director of the movie thought "bag of hammers" had a different meaning, and only found out later the widely-known meaning.

Comment: If life gives you a bag of hammers, build a life?

Answer (score 17):

Originally, the proverbial **bag of hammers** was *noisy* (and by implication, *unsubtle*)...

> They would come down on her with the celerity of a **bag of hammers** [(1913)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1SZMAAAAYAAJ&q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&dq=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vRmWUY7BJaGc0QXVjICIDg&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBQ)
>   (where *celerity = speed, noise, lack of subtlety*).
>
> you should listen to yon engines of mine. They clatter like a **bag of hammers** [(1923)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E-7PAAAAMAAJ&q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&dq=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vRmWUY7BJaGc0QXVjICIDg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAg)

That usage was never particularly common - I can find only [another 3-4 written instances](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&biw=1258&bih=865&sa=X&ei=AyiWUYO9O4bA0QWMxIHIDA&ved=0CCUQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1940,cd_max:31/12/1980&tbm=bks#q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1940,cd_max:31/12/1980&tbm=bks&ei=diiWUfHTItTJ0AW8woGYBA&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46471029,d.d2k&fp=fc796f5a29a646d0&biw=1258&bih=865) before it suddenly [re-emerged and became more widespread in the 80s](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&biw=1258&bih=865&sa=X&ei=EiiWUYWfNNGl0wWWg4GwAQ&ved=0CCgQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1980,cd_max:31/12/1990&tbm=bks#q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1980,cd_max:31/12/1990&tbm=bks&ei=NyiWUf3YO-Sp0AWvnYCYBQ&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46471029,d.d2k&fp=fc796f5a29a646d0&biw=1258&bih=865) with various different senses...

> A mug as ugly as a **bag of hammers** [(1985, *mug = face*)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Aue-AAAAIAAJ&q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&dq=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nSmWUZSRD-nR0QXRw4DoDQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwADgK)
>    Your father was crazy as a **bag of hammers** [(1989](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BDi2AAAAIAAJ&q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&dq=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nSmWUZSRD-nR0QXRw4DoDQ&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAzgK)

...around the same time as the **spanners** version first appeared...

> She's got a face like a **bag of spanners** ([1981](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qNFBAQAAIAAJ&q=%22a%20bag%20of%20spanners%22&dq=%22a%20bag%20of%20spanners%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8iqWUYuhCcqM0wWymoCwDw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAA) and [1982](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EqUnAQAAIAAJ&q=%22a%20bag%20of%20spanners%22&dq=%22a%20bag%20of%20spanners%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8iqWUYuhCcqM0wWymoCwDw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAQ))

---

In recent decades, **bag of hammers** is [almost exclusively American](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bag%20of%20hammers,bag%20of%20spanners&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) (where it's normally used to mean *dumb, stupid*), and **bag of spanners** is [British](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bag%20of%20hammers,bag%20of%20spanners&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) (invariably used to mean *ugly*).

Note that the [crazy](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&biw=1258&bih=865&sa=X&ei=EiiWUYWfNNGl0wWWg4GwAQ&ved=0CCgQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1980,cd_max:31/12/1990&tbm=bks#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22crazy%20as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&oq=%22crazy%20as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&gs_l=serp.3...31764.34031.3.34511.8.8.0.0.0.0.77.445.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.DfVIb-YDiA8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=fc796f5a29a646d0&biw=1258&bih=865), [mad](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&biw=1258&bih=865&sa=X&ei=EiiWUYWfNNGl0wWWg4GwAQ&ved=0CCgQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1980,cd_max:31/12/1990&tbm=bks#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22mad%20as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&oq=%22mad%20as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&gs_l=serp.3...55375.57518.4.57734.8.8.0.0.0.0.77.461.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.DNdhUoqxuqE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=fc796f5a29a646d0&biw=1258&bih=865) sense for **hammers** is relatively uncommon - that's less than 30 results in total for both collocations, whereas [**dumb** as a bag of hammers](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&biw=1258&bih=865&sa=X&ei=EiiWUYWfNNGl0wWWg4GwAQ&ved=0CCgQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1980,cd_max:31/12/1990&tbm=bks#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22dumb%20as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&oq=%22dumb%20as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&gs_l=serp.3...67504.69160.5.69914.7.7.0.0.0.0.79.405.7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.2qqZlzDhW10&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=fc796f5a29a646d0&biw=1258&bih=865) has a claimed 1140 instances. As @Matt points out, those few instances of the *crazy* sense probably arise by association with phrases such as [crazy as a **box** of frogs/weasels/crackers](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22CRAZY%20AS%20A%20BOX%20OF%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and [mad as a **bag** of ferrets/snakes/cats](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22CRAZY%20AS%20A%20BOX%20OF%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22mad%20AS%20A%20Bag%20OF%22&oq=%22mad%20AS%20A%20Bag%20OF%22&gs_l=serp.3...53633.55486.1.55900.8.8.0.0.0.0.76.393.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.EeoXcUWCl-w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46471029,d.d2k&fp=fc796f5a29a646d0&biw=1258&bih=865).

---

The answer to OP's specific question ("Does *bag of hammers* have a "stable" meaning?") is probably "Yes", if we restrict ourselves to *current* usages. It's not hard to find contemporary [examples](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E-2F9W8AzLwC&q=%22as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&dq=%22as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7JmWUfmHLubI0QX0noDACA&ved=0CGIQ6AEwCTgU) [with](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22heavy%20as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) [a](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Nbba_QjIwpUC&pg=PA197&dq=%22as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XJuWUffBFaal0AXOqoAY&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&f=false) [different](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_sP840g2OdgC&pg=PA154&dq=%22as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XJuWUffBFaal0AXOqoAY&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&f=false) [sense](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xH0fAQAAIAAJ&q=%22as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&dq=%22as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XJuWUffBFaal0AXOqoAY&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCA) (each of those five words links to one), but they're vanishingly rare compared to the *dumb* usage which now dominates.

But as commented by @Bradd below, [dumb as a box of rocks](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dumb%20as%20a%20box%20of%20rocks%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is 3-4 times more common than the [bag of hammers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dumb%20as%20a%20bag%20of%20hammers%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) version. Besides which, the usage itself seems inherently "dumb" to me, in that *hammers* have no obvious (even metaphoric) connection with *stupidity* - I'm sure the expression only arose in the first place via inaccurate repetition of usages that *do* make metaphorical sense.

Comment: _Dumb as a bag of hammers_ is less common than _dumb as a box of rocks._ Both express about the same thing though: duller than a bunch of dull things.

Comment: @Bradd: You're quite right that the proverbial ***box** of rocks* is far more common than anything above, in respect of *dumb=stupid*. I think it's very American though (Brits tend to say *"thick as two short planks"*). But the *box/bag of **hammers*** version is different, in that no-one seriously thinks of hammers as being particularly stupid/dull. Those versions *only* exist as (unwitting?) variants of pre-existing expressions involving meaningful metaphors.

Comment: I mean dull as in blunt – and blunt/dull things get used in metaphors about stupidity.

Comment: @Bradd: Indeed. Many people probably see *dull = stupid* as a "metaphorical" extension from *dull = not sharp[-witted]*. But checking with OED I see they postulate it came from OE *dyl = foolish*. On the other hand, *stupid* (defined as *having one's faculties deadened or **dulled***) derives from Latin *stupēre = to be stunned or benumbed*, so arguably *dull* means *stupid* more "literally" than *stupid* itself does.

Comment: Can't believe I've gone my whole life without ever hearing `dumb as a box of rocks`. What a wonderful expression! If I hadn't been told it was American, I'd have pegged it as Australian for sure, though. Just has that certain Aussie cadence to it....

Comment: I remember Foghorn Leghorn saying "nice girl but about as sharp as a sack of wet mice."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hammers are dumb when they struck your thumb; note it is striking the thumb that makes *them* dumb.

Answer (score 3):

There is the expression ["mad as a bag of hammers"](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/mad+as+a+bag+of+hammers.html) that means "crazy". I imagine that's where the film gets its name from.

Other phrases with the same meaning:

- "mad as a box of frogs"
- "mad as a bag of spanners"
- "mad as a March hare"

Comment: My experience of *bag of spanners* has been with respect to the noise certain car engines make. I've never heard it in any other context (and I'm in the UK too). But then I've never heard of *bag of hammers* either.

Comment: They're both relatively common expressions where I'm from. Maybe that reflects more on the people I know...

Comment: I'm British, and the only one of those that I've ever heard is *mad as a March hare* - and it's a looooong time since I've heard that.

Comment: @TrevorD You and Andrew are from the south east. I'm from the west and south west. Maybe the phrase is stuck over this way?

Comment: @MattЭллен Thanks. I actually looked at your profile to see where you were from before I answered - but I didn't even know what continent *Black Crag* is in, let alone which country! [P.s. I've now noticed the link to your website, which does clarify the country!]

Answer (score 3):

Dumber than a bag of hammers is a well known saying that means stupid. Similar to not being the brightest light on the porch or the sharpest knife in the drawer. A well-known usage occurs in the Coen Brothers movie Oh Brother, Where Art Thou?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the expression *as ugly as a bag of hammers*, to describe someone who is particularly ill-favoured in the beauty stakes. I can't find any online reference to it, but the similar expression *ugly as bag of spanners* is noted [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=699067).

Why a bag of anything should be thought ugly I can't begin to imagine.

Comment: Presumably a bag of hammers would have a lumpy, misshapen exterior, since the items contained within do not tesselate very well. Equating someone's face to such a shape doesn't seem that big a leap to make (for the type of person who would make such a comment on someone's appearance).

Comment: @David John Welsh: Per my answer, I suspect the *ugly* sense (which is relatively uncommon by comparison with *stupid, dumb* and *crazy, mad*) probably arises from confusion with BrE *bag of **spanners***, which always means *ugly*. Americans tend to use *wrench* rather than *spanner* in other contexts, so if they're repeating the vaguely-recalled BrE version they might well remember the meaning, but change the tool to something more familiar. In the real world it's not uncommon to keep many spanners in a bag (or canvas "tool-roll"), but that wouldn't be so likely with hammers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Heh, that's true. I didn't think of it till you said it, but I guess it would be a little harder to imagine a situation that called for several different sizes or types of hammer. And pronunciationwise, `hammer` and `spanner` share a certain musicality, at least in this phrase, that `wrench` doesn't match.

Comment: @David: Exactly. It's really just "armchair theorising" on my part, but the *hammer/spanner* alliteration does seem to have the ring of truth. And there's no doubt *a face like a bag of spanners" is familiar to most UK speakers, but Americans invariably [use a wrench](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use+a+wrench%2Cuse+a+spanner&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) where Brits use a spanner.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this site after hearing [**Thao with the Get Down Stay Down** - ***Bag of Hammers***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57OtoBN_Jig)

So how about this,

"Bag of Hammers" as referring to various and assorted "**issues**" (problems)

For instance, imagine oneself carrying around a "Bag of Hammers"

Answer (score 0):

The actor Michael J. Fox has often used the expression to mean "anything that makes life more difficult." For him, Parkinson's Disease is his bag of hammers. A box of hammers would be heavy, more awkward to carry than a box of hammers, and while you may have use for a single hammer, a bag full of them would be an unnecessary burden to handle.